# What do you exactly mean by the area bounded when it comes to integration

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I am trying to understand this term when it comes to integrating the function to find out areas.

Is it correct to say that for the curve $y=e^{(x-1)/2}-2$, is the shaded region is **bounded** by the following?

- the curve
- $x$-axis
- $y$-xis
- the line $x=3$

[image: example]

If we consider the next shaded area for the curve $y=x(x-1)$, is it correct to say that the shaded area is bounded by:

- the curve
- the $x$-axis
- the line $x=1$
- and the line $x=0$ (this one I am not sure)

[image: example2]

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Since the function is negative, the area is $-\int_{0}^{1}x(x-1)dx.$

Comment: My friend thinks that I should not say "the second curve is bounded by $x=0$" as it has nothing to do with the area. What do you think?

Comment: $x=0$ follows directly from what was given. Even if you write only two first of your  conditions, the values $0$ and $1$ are bounds for the integral. It is because for $x<0$ or $x>1$, there is no bounded area between the graph and $x$-axis.

Comment: The question in the title does not match the questions in the body of your post.